# Does parameter sequence matters php get request

Tags: php, get

I used get request many times but didn't care about the sequence in which these parameters are being sent. There is a case of WooCoomerce REST API. i failed many times to get exact signature because i was not sending all GET parameters in sequence. Can anybody explains does parameter order matters in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the parameter sequence doesn't matter. It is just the transfer of data from client to server. The data you pass is passed as a bunch, then you start processing it in your code. Hence, all the data comes together.

Comment: Please ready my question carefully. I am generating signature in woocommerce rest api. Have a look at http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication

Comment: After reading the above link, the doc clearly says that it is sorting the parameters in byte-order. Hence, I feel there is a specific order the API asks for. Can you give an example URL, that you are using? 

The order generally doesn't matter, but if the API asks for it then, API might need parameters to be in order to process. You can try looking at the processing code on github if you are curious.

Comment: No i am just testing it on my local machine. Is it confirm that only specific api requires parameter sequence?

Comment: Yes, it is specific to the API. The order generally doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

No, parameter order should not matter at all in any HTTP request. They are all parsed before they get to your script.

Comment: But there is a case where its order matters. When we are generating signature in woocommerce rest api.

Comment: Have a look at http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication, uksort is being used